# Django - can't get production web server running

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Django app in production, on an apache server, using mod-wsgi. mod-wsgi is installed and working fine. When I run the Django server, it launches fine, but I can't access it on the server or online, and I don't understand why. I'm posting the relevant section of `ports.conf` (for apache), and my `wsgi.py` (automatically generated as pinax.wsgi when I created my project, renamed to wsgi.py, this does not affect anything) script below.

ports.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName <myserver>.org

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/<myapp>-env/pinax-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite

WSGIScriptAlias / /<myapp>/deploy/wsgi.py
<Directory /<myapp>/deploy>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
# pinax.wsgi is configured to live in projects/<myapp>/deploy.

import os
import sys

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from site import addsitedir

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../")))

From django.conf import settings
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "<myapp>.settings"

sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is. What happens when you try to access it? Do you get an error? If so, what error?